# YARN ResourceTrackerService failed in state STARTED

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to setup a hadoop cluster on a few machines with Hadoop Directory on a shared disk. HDFS worked well. But when I try to start YARN, ResourceTracker throws a BindException. The node (ahti.d.umn.edu-131.212.41.9) on which ResourceTracker is cofigured to run is reachable (I can SSH into it) and the port (28025) is also open.

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService failed in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [ahti.d.umn.edu:28025] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
    org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [ahti.d.umn.edu:28025] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC.getServer(HadoopYarnProtoRPC.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.YarnRPC.getServer(YarnRPC.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService.serviceStart(ResourceTrackerService.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:898)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:938)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:935)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.transitionToActive(ResourceManager.java:935)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:979)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1104)
```

Following is my yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>131.212.41.9</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>       
 <value>131.212.41.9:28025</value>  
</property>

<property>       
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>       
 <value>131.212.41.9:8030</value>  
</property>

<property>       
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>       
 <value>131.212.41.9:8050</value>  
</property>

<property>       
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>       
 <value>131.212.41.9:8041</value>  
</property>

<property>       
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>       
 <value>/scratch/dfs/yarn</value>  
</property>

<property>       
 <name>yarn.log.dir</name>       
 <value>/scratch/hadoop/yarn/logs</value>  
</property>

</configuration>
```

If it matters I am running java-8.

Any clues on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be because of two reasons

May be some other instance of Resource manager already running that uses the port. Kill that Resource manager instance and start again. Find the process id of resource manager using the command `ps aux | grep -i resourcemanager`, then kill the same using the command `kill  -9 <RESOURCE_MANAGER_PID>`

Hadoop doesn't fully support JDK-8. See the [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions) for Hadoop supported Java versions, If option 1 is not working, try downgrade your java version to JDK7